# Replace NAs with a string in RODBC sqlQuery() function

Tags: sql, r

How can I replace `NA` items when using `RODBC` database language in `R`?

I searched a lot, but it seems there is nothing like `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` functions, I tried `CASE` operator too, but no luck!

Here is my query. In the result I want to use a string like `Not Captured` instead of `<NA>`:

```
sql <- "SELECT PRODUCT_LINE, COUNT(*) AS MMR_Count,
ROUND((COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(MMR_NBR) FROM hist_mmr)),2) AS per
FROM hist_MMR
GROUP BY PRODUCT_LINE
ORDER BY COUNT(PRODUCT_LINE) DESC"

df <- sqlQuery( db , sql) 

head(df,10)
```

**Result:**

```
  PRODUCT_LINE MMR_Count   per
1     SECURITY       688 43.60
2     PLUMBING       320 20.28
3     HARDWARE        80  5.07
4         <NA>       490 31.05
```

**Desired Result:**

```
PRODUCT_LINE MMR_Count   per
  PRODUCT_LINE MMR_Count   per
1     SECURITY       688 43.60
2     PLUMBING       320 20.28
3     HARDWARE        80  5.07
4 Not Captured       490 31.05
```

Comment: BTW: if you're looking for a SQL solution, you should include the specific server type (sqlserver, postgres, mariadb, etc).

Comment: No, I don't have a problem with SQL solution, my problem was R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me when connecting to SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. Granted, it's not using `RODBC`, but I suspect your need is more SQL-centric and not `RODBC`-specific.

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select (case when 1=2 then 'a' else 'b' end) as a")
#   a
# 1 b
```

So in your situation, I suspect this could work (untested):

```
sql <- "
  SELECT 
    (case when PRODUCT_LINE is null then 'No Captured' else PRODUCT_LINE end),
    COUNT(*) AS MMR_Count,
    ROUND((COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(MMR_NBR) FROM hist_mmr)),2) AS per
  FROM hist_MMR
  GROUP BY PRODUCT_LINE
  ORDER BY COUNT(PRODUCT_LINE) DESC
"
```

(For the record, I'm using [`DBI`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html) with [`RSQLServer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLServer/index.html), [`RPostgres`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RPostgres/index.html), and [`RSQLite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html).)

You can also solve this in R with:

```
df$PRODUCT_LINE[is.na(df$PRODUCT_LINE)] <- "Not Captured"
```

Comment: `CASE` operator is not working as I mentioned earlier. The second resort is also good, but it is not working on my end, this is the message I am getting: `Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df$PRODUCT_LINE), value = c(3L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: Sorry, you said you tried it but since I didn't see the code, I was guessing perhaps that it was used incorrectly. For the second, it seems like your return is a `factor`, so either update the `levels` of the column, or first run `df$PRODUCT_LINE <- as.character(df$PRODUCT_LINE)` and then the `[is.na(...` command.